# Repeated Image Outputs through OpenCV Template Matching

Tags: python, image, csv, opencv, pdf

The following code reads the set of input tiff files under tiffile and template tiff files under file and performs template matching on them. After the image gets matched, OpenCV contour extracts the areas where the output of template matching is less than the threshold (which would be given by the user). The problem is that image is getting matched more than once.
When I used the template to extract the maps on a page, instead of two maps on the page, I got many maps as these maps were detected more than once).
How do I avoid this?. I tried increasing the threshold value, the number of template images, but it still didn't help that much. I tried to decrease the number of template images, removed the i and k coordinates (Searching within an image even after matched once) from the code, it still didn't work.

Here is the code,

**Template Matching Function**

```
def matchtemplatetiff(tifffile, file, outdir, threshold):
    img = np.array(PIL.Image.open(tifffile))
    tmp = np.array(PIL.Image.open(file))
    imgc=img.copy()
    w, h, c = tmp.shape
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, tmp, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
    # create empty lists to append the coord of the
    lspoint = []
    lspoint2 =[]
    count = 0
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    n=0
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        # check that the coords are not already in the list, if they are then skip the match
        if pt[0] not in lspoint and pt[1] not in lspoint2:
            # draw a yellow boundary around a match
            size =w * h * (2.54/400) *( 2.54/400)
            # data rows of csv file   
            rows = 0
            m=0
            rows = [[tifffile, w, h , pt[1] + w, pt[0] + h, size, threshold, (time.time() - start_time)]]    
            cv2.imwrite(tifffile+ 'map' + str(n) + str(m)+'.tif', imgc[ pt[1]:(pt[1] + w), pt[0]:(pt[0] + h), :])
            # name of csv file   
            filename = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/records_first.csv"
            # writing to csv file   
            with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:   
           # creating a csv writer object   
               csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)   
          # writing the fields   
               csvwriter.writerow(fields)   
          # writing the data rows   
               csvwriter.writerows(rows)
            for i in range(((pt[0])-9), ((pt[0])+9), 1):
            ## append the x cooord
                 lspoint.append(i)
            for k in range(((pt[1])-9), ((pt[1])+9), 1):
            ## append the y coord
                 lspoint.append(k)
            count+=1
            n=n+1
            m=m+1
        else:
            continue
    print(tifffile)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    PIL.Image.fromarray(img, 'RGB').save(os.path.join(outdir, os.path.basename(tifffile)))
```

**Batch Processing of Files**

```
threshold = 0.15
print("Entered threshold value",threshold)
#main image folder
for tifffile in glob.glob("/content/drive/MyDrive/testpakistan/*.tif"):
#templates folder
    for file in glob.glob("/content/drive/MyDrive/templatepakistan/*.tif"):        
         matchtemplatetiff(tifffile, file, "/content/drive/MyDrive/testpakistan/",threshold)
```

Comment: Can you please post an executable code sample, and sample input image (and template) that reproduces the problem. What do you want the output to be, when there are multiple matches?

Comment: Just search for the best match (max value) and not a contour.

Comment: Just add the main folder to read the tif files in the main folder and template folder in this, for tifffile in glob.glob(main folder/* .tif"): , for file in glob.glob(template folder/*.tif"):, matchtemplatetiff(tifffile, file, outputfolder,threshold).

Comment: I am not searching for contour, I am searching for the points that are higher than the threshold.